# VSCode not showing DOCUMENT_ROOT as per php.ini

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to debug a PHP code. I have installed VSCode with PHP in XAMPP setup. The code runs fine in the Firefox browser.

When I run it in the debugger in VS Code, it seems to not read the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and shows it as empty. Also, the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` shows as undefined array key.

Error Message in VS Code:

> Exception has occurred.
> Warning: Undefined array key "REMOTE_ADDR"

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
$a = "hello";
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
session_destroy();
?>
```

XDEBUG SETTINGS IN PHP.INI

```
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Aids    ✔ enabled   
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled   
Tracing ✘ disabled

[xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable= 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.idekey = "ls.xdebug"
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.remote_mode = req
sdebug.mode=debug
;xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

Please suggest as to why some php.ini settings are not showing as available in the Global arrays `$_SERVER`.

Comment: You must be debugging the script in the CLI and not as a web page (via browser). Double check that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why these would be empty - I don't think that's an Xdebug issue. Perhaps you're starting the script with a CLI version of PHP. If that is the case, there is no REMOTE_ADDR (or I suspect, DOCUMENT_ROOT).

I can explain why this runs "fine" in Firefox, and not through the debugger in VS Code. By default, the VS Code plugin set a breakpoint on "everything", as you can see in the bottom left of this image:

[image]

The "Everything" means that VS Code set a breakpoint on every exception, warning, and notice, which is why Xdebug stops here. You can untick "Everything", and then it should no longer show the warning in VS Code.